# "Потому что надежно" ― нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, реклама

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в слогане?
**Потому что надежно.**

Comment: Пишется без запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Слоган ― это сообщение с многообразными функциями: информативной, экспрессивной, побудительной, убеждающей.

Потому что ― это сложный (составной) подчинительный союз, с его помощью вы коротко отвечаете на вопрос "почему?". **Потому что надёжно!**
Расчленение союза (то есть постановка запятой) в этом случае не требуется.

**Потому что люблю** (название фильма).
**Потому что гладиолус** (используется в сети как универсальный ответ на любой вопрос).